Estimating Multinomial Logit using xlogit vs. statsmodels
I am trying to estimate a multinomial logit with Python for a discrete choice model. I come from R, where the estimation of the coefficients is the same, but not the predictions.
I am using a known dataset of yogurts. I download it in R with data(yogurt) in long format.
I got my first prediction using the package xlogit:
Optimization terminated successfully.
    Message: The gradients are close to zero
    Iterations: 11
    Function evaluations: 12
Estimation time= 0.0 seconds
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Coefficient              Estimate      Std.Err.         z-val         P>|z|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
_intercept.hiland      -3.7156022     0.1454191   -25.5509897     1.21e-127 ***
_intercept.weight      -0.6411846     0.0544983   -11.7652278      4.11e-31 ***
_intercept.yoplait      0.7345696     0.0806442     9.1087765       1.7e-19 ***
price                  -0.3665841     0.0243661   -15.0448680      5.79e-49 ***
feat                    0.4914337     0.1200630     4.0931314       4.4e-05 ***
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Significance:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Log-Likelihood= -2656.888
AIC= 5323.776
BIC= 5352.717

I tried statsmodels and I loved it, because it gives back many metrics that I need, like the R2 of McFadden. For this, I converted the data to wide format.
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 1.064086
         Iterations 8
                          MNLogit Regression Results                          
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                 choice   No. Observations:                 2412
Model:                        MNLogit   Df Residuals:                     2385
Method:                           MLE   Df Model:                           24
Date:                Mon, 27 May 2024   Pseudo R-squ.:                 0.09402
Time:                        12:54:04   Log-Likelihood:                -2566.6
converged:                       True   LL-Null:                       -2832.9
Covariance Type:            nonrobust   LLR p-value:                 2.632e-97
==================================================================================
 choice=hiland       coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const              4.1582      1.971      2.110      0.035       0.295       8.021
featdannon        -0.0743      0.802     -0.093      0.926      -1.646       1.498
feathiland         1.1137      0.462      2.412      0.016       0.209       2.019
featweight         0.5323      0.687      0.775      0.438      -0.814       1.879
featyoplait       -0.1600      0.753     -0.212      0.832      -1.635       1.316
pricedannon        0.2312      0.144      1.600      0.110      -0.052       0.514
pricehiland       -0.8970      0.155     -5.794      0.000      -1.201      -0.594
priceweight       -0.2053      0.163     -1.259      0.208      -0.525       0.114
priceyoplait      -0.2371      0.073     -3.244      0.001      -0.380      -0.094
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
choice=weight       coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const             1.6081      0.878      1.831      0.067      -0.113       3.329
featdannon       -0.3334      0.319     -1.046      0.295      -0.958       0.291
feathiland       -1.1772      0.382     -3.079      0.002      -1.927      -0.428
featweight        0.7189      0.287      2.502      0.012       0.156       1.282
featyoplait       0.0913      0.280      0.326      0.745      -0.458       0.641
pricedannon       0.1513      0.059      2.570      0.010       0.036       0.267
pricehiland      -0.5736      0.078     -7.392      0.000      -0.726      -0.422
priceweight      -0.1966      0.076     -2.574      0.010      -0.346      -0.047
priceyoplait      0.1134      0.046      2.440      0.015       0.022       0.205
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
choice=yoplait       coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const              0.0535      0.869      0.062      0.951      -1.650       1.757
featdannon         0.4482      0.314      1.427      0.154      -0.168       1.064
feathiland         0.0552      0.328      0.168      0.866      -0.587       0.698
featweight        -0.4865      0.328     -1.483      0.138      -1.129       0.156
featyoplait        0.3402      0.224      1.519      0.129      -0.099       0.779
pricedannon        0.7023      0.067     10.503      0.000       0.571       0.833
pricehiland       -0.1863      0.072     -2.586      0.010      -0.327      -0.045
priceweight       -0.1383      0.080     -1.724      0.085      -0.296       0.019
priceyoplait      -0.3676      0.035    -10.627      0.000      -0.435      -0.300
==================================================================================

Later, when I tried predicting the probabilities I obtained different results. For the xlogit model I had to do it manually, since it doesn't predict probs.
I'd like to understand if I can do something to obtain the same results in both predictions. Am I doing everything right with statsmodels?
Also, how can I compute the R2-McFadden manually if it's not possible to obtain them from xlogit?
Is there any other package that replicates the libraries from R: logitr or mlogit?

I don't know xlogit. The number of parameters differs and it looks like that they are not estimating the same multinomial model. For example statsmodels MNLogit includes all cross-price effects, xlogit seems to have only one price parameter.

statsmodels does not have a multinomial model where explanatory variables differ by choice variable but parameters are common to choices.
